# Solr Occasionally Stops working. How can I debug it or detect what has happened?

Tags: solr

Every few weeks, solr becomes unavailable.  The search page on the website that uses it breaks and the solr web admin becomes unreachable (Unable to connect)

Here is what solr status says:

```
root@wairc-kman-1:/var/solr/logs# service solr status
● solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-07-07 16:28:25 UTC; 2 weeks 6 days ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2338)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/solr.service

Jul 07 16:28:16 wairc-kman-1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service...
Jul 07 16:28:16 wairc-kman-1 su[720036]: (to solr) root on none
Jul 07 16:28:16 wairc-kman-1 su[720036]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user solr by (uid=0)
Jul 07 16:28:25 wairc-kman-1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
```

The websites log says:

```
Uncaught Exception GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8983: Connection refused
```

I can't find anything more recent than a week ago in the solr log /var/www/solr/logs/solr.log

Restarting "fixes" the error  - solr becomes reachable again.  How can I debug this? or detect it and restart when needed?

Comment: You may still find some interesting logs in `/var/log/messages` at the time Solr becomes unavailable. Did you check the server memory (JVM) and disk space ? If you "can't find anything more recent than a week ago", it could be that you have a logging policy that is too heavy for your system, especially if it has no room, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330604/solr-server-memory-and-disk-space). Also, as strange as it sounds, it happens (well, at least to me on CentOS 7) that running Solr via SysVInit won't track Solr status correctly, while SystemD (systemctl) will.

Comment: You could create a cronjob that runs a specific script every minute, that script would check Solr status using the [Ping API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/ping.html) and take appropriate measures in case of unavailability. There are other [admin endpoints](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/implicit-requesthandlers.html#admin-handlers) like 'health' and 'system' (ie. for tracking memory usage) that might be useful to get a grasp of what's going on (I would log their outputs every 6 hours in a dedicated log file).

Comment: Solr disappearing is usually caused by the OOM (out of memory) killer terminating the process. You'll find a log entry in `/var/log/syslog` or in `/var/log/messages` in that case. Adjust the available memory in that case; `journalctl` might also be helpful to get any foreground/systemd errors from the process itself.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  @MatsLindh - if it is terminating the process wouldnt the status look different?

Comment: @EricLavault - pinging solr seems like the way to go, then just stop and start it.   Im struggling to see how to do that in a sh script though.  restarting simple enough but how do I run the ping and check the response?

Comment: I would use the same HTTP client that I usually use for querying Solr. If you are using Guzzle, create a php script that ping and echoes the status with guzzle, and in the shell script, just curl that script. You can also get the output of the 'health' endpoint directly from the shell using the [healthcheck](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/solr-control-script-reference.html#healthcheck) command (SolrCloud mode only).